# Ajax cache issue? Or something else?

Tags: sql-server, caching, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have a web part inside a sharepoint page that ask the server for data. To do this I am making an ajax request in my code like the following one

```
function GetPeriod() {
    var period;
    $.ajax({
        url: GetBaseWSUrl() + 'MyWebService.asmx/GetPeriod',
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            period = data.d;
        }
    });
    return period;
}
```

Inside the web service `MyWebService.asmx` I have the method `GetPeriod()` which in turn query the database for data and return this data as a JSON object.

I am experiencing a problem in a piece of code which does the following things:

1. First the code calls the `GetPeriod()` function
2. Then the user can change some data and submit the changes to the server
3. Finally the code calls again the `GetPeriod()` function

When I am calling the `GetPeriod()` function at the point n° 3 I am not able to see the updated data even if those data are correctly saved on the database!

At first I thought to be a problem of synchronicity and so I have added the `async: false` param but it did'nt solve the issue. 
Now I am thinking that is a cache problem (because the data has been correctly saved to the database) so I did try with the `cache: false` param but none of these solutions works for me.

I have also tried to put the database under profiling and I can see that the effective request is called even if I can see a discrepancy between the time the http request has been issued by the client and the time effectively the query get executed on the database.

I am completely getting lost about this....

Any helps?

Comment: is this happening in all browsers? or just ie?

Comment: @Patricia: I am just trying with IE8/9 because of the sharepoint :)

Comment: right, of course.  I've had an issue wit the cache:false option in the past. I'll put how i solved it in an answer.

Comment: Try to define `var period;` outside GetPeriod function scope.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before.   and solved it by putting:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
    cache: false
});
```

i don't know why the cache option as part of your $.ajax doesn't work, but this might.

Comment: Thanks Patricia. I am just doing this way but nothing... :(

Comment: the parameter isn't being stuck to the end of your request?